# Sqlite. Table unpivot

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table & want to make some data processing (convert it from 4 columns to 2):

[image]

So, desired output will looks like below:

```
cue        relation
although   neverthel...
although   yet
although   but
deal       no 
deal       cards
deal       shake
music      notes
music      band
music      rhythm
```

Does it possible by using SQLITE engine?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather say UNPIVOT here. You can simply do `UNION ALL`, with one SELECT for each R column.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to numbers, then use a `CASE WHEN` for the relation column.

```
select *
from
(
  select cue
  , case column1
    when 1 then R1
    when 2 then R2
    when 3 then R3
    end relation
  from your_table t
  cross join (values (1),(2),(3)) n
) q
where relation is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create new table that will consist of data as you wish.
I called your table as : `origin_table` and the new one as: `two_col_table`

```
create table two_col_table (cue varchar2(22), relation varchar2(22));

insert into two_col_table(cue, relation) SELECT cue, r1 FROM origin_table;
insert into two_col_table(cue, relation) SELECT cue, r2 FROM origin_table;
insert into two_col_table(cue, relation) SELECT cue, r3 FROM origin_table;

SELECT * FROM two_col_table ORDER BY CUE;
```